How to discard builds if older than daysToKeep AND more then numToKeep?
Automatic removal of old builds and artifacts is great to avoid lots of data building up and filling disks. For some job that runs 0-5 times per day we might have this setting:
numToKeep: 20
daysToKeep: 10

But with this setting Jenkins will clean out historic data when EITHER of these criteria are no longer met.
For example, if there is low activity for a month (e.g. vacation period) it might happen that the job hasn't run for 2 weeks. In this case Jenkins will delete all historic builds since they are older than 10 days. This is not wanted.
Another example: if we run it for 5 times every day we might get a history that is only 4 days old before we hit the limit of 20 items. This is not wanted either.
Instead:
Is it possible to always keep a history of at least 10 builds AND at least 10 days?

Out of the box Jenkins cannot do that, but there are plugins that allow more granular control. discard-old-build is one of them, but I'm sure there are others.
